# Realm Conflict / ClassCastException on release builds

Tags: android, realm, butterknife

On live builds using

```
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.4'

(compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0')
```

I get an Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$VarSymbol cannot be cast to javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
at io.realm.processor.RealmProcessor.process(RealmProcessor.java:131)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
```

What could be the problem? A dependency conflict? We are using:

```
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
}
```

Should we add anything more here?

**==== EDIT 1 ====**

Console also gives this output (everything below here, also the possible solutions):

```
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$VarSymbol cannot be cast to javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
```

Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

**==== EDIT 2 ====**

- I turned off Proguard now
- I removed butterknife from the project completely

Problem still there...

Comment: your using proguard for obfuscation if yes then check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An afternoon of crazy trial and error later, I found it. Someone added a @Nullable annotation with the wrong import.

```
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
```

And that, only on release (exporting) APK's, caused the issue.

Just removing the Nullable annotation or changing the import into:

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
```

fixed the problem.

I found it by installing Java 8. Than the IDE gives you a specific error, and not the general stacktrace posted in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

There might be issue in your `butterknife` & `realm` library version dependencies.

```
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.81.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
```

For more info go through below link [issue github](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/885)

**Note:-** If not resolved, check the import for annotation which your using.

Comment: are you using annotation or extending the model by RealObject

Comment: I'm extending RealObject. Why?

Comment: can u drop your model class then only I will get where is the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using our AAR distribution instead of the JAR to see if it fixes it. You can see how here: https://realm.io/news/android-installation-change/

The latest version is 0.87.4